# Send Adaptive card (Json payload) with your c# code to teams

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I have a very simple incoming webhook code that allows me to have contact with teams and send some message, now I want to print this Json file with a card into Teams...
I have a very simple incoming webhook code that allows me to have contact with teams and send some message, now I want to print this Json file with a card into Teams ...
My goal with this is that I should be able to put values ​​in my Json file and be able to send it away just like I do when I test run in Postman ...
Declaring values ​​is not my problem but how I should then write this out

**Json payload**

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "themeColor": "D82148",
    "summary": " new Order",
    "sections": [{
        "activityTitle": "New Order To Pick.",
        "activitySubtitle": "On Project Tango",
        "activityImage": "https://teamsnodesample.azurewebsites.net/static/img/image5.png",
        "facts": [{
            "name": "Assigned to",
            "value": "Unassigned"
        }, {
            "name": "Due date",
            "value": "Mon May 01 2017 17:07:18 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
        }, {
            "name": "Status",
            "value": "Not started"
        }],
        "markdown": true
    }],
    "potentialAction": [{
        "@type": "ActionCard",
        "name": "Change status",
        "inputs": [{
            "@type": "MultichoiceInput",
            "id": "list",
            "title": "Select a status",
            "isMultiSelect": "false",
            "choices": [{
                "display": "In Progress",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "display": "Active",
                "value": "2"
            }, {
                "display": "Closed",
                "value": "3"
            }]
        }],
        "actions": [{
            "@type": "HttpPOST",
            "name": "Save",
            "target": "https://learn.microsoft.com/outlook/actionable-messages"
        }]
    }]
}
```

**My program code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TeamsConectTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            string webhookUrl = "<TeamsUrl>";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webhookUrl);

            Message body = new Message();


            

            string serializeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

            StringContent content = new StringContent(serializeJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            _ = await client.PostAsync(requestUri: client.BaseAddress, content);

        }

       
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue while sending the Card to Teams?
You can also refer this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL

Comment: @Zipsam - Could you please confirm if the above suggestion helped you in any way or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: I would use AdaptiveCard NuGet package to generate json dynamically instead of a long string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/authoring-cards/net